# Rails: fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I've seen a lot of these questions around but none have the answer I need. Most have either postgres setup issues or password typoes, etc.

I am having an issue with a Postgres database connection that's not working right, with Rails 3.2.

- Postgres 9.1 is working just fine for other rails projects. The `pg_hba.conf` is set to the defaults and has never needed changing.
- I am using a pretty much identical database.yml file with other projects, just with the db name different. I've never had this issue before, and I have about 20 other rails projects that use postgres all working fine.
- I'm connecting with a db owner named `postgres`

My `database.yml` file:

```
connection: &connection
  adapter: postgresql
  username: postgres
  password: mypassword
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *connection
  database: projectname_development

test:
  <<: *connection
  database: projectname_test

production:
  <<: *connection
  database: projectname_production
```

The error I get is:

```
/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -S rspec   
./spec/controllers/keyword_lists_controller_spec.rb     
./spec/controllers/map_keywords_controller_spec.rb ./spec/full_stack/document_import_spec.rb   
./spec/html_content/defined_terms_wrapper_spec.rb 
./spec/html_content/reference_relation_builder_spec.rb ./spec/lib/caches_children_spec.rb 
./spec/logic/content_formatting/content_node_formatter_spec.rb 
./spec/logic/content_formatting/table_formatter_spec.rb 
./spec/logic/content_formatting/text_run_formatter_spec.rb  
./spec/logic/document_processor_spec.rb ./spec/logic/hierarchy_tracker_spec.rb 
./spec/logic/map_builder/content_factory_spec.rb 
./spec/logic/map_builder/page_break_content_factory_spec.rb 
./spec/logic/map_builder/table_content_factory_spec.rb 
./spec/logic/map_builder/text_run_content_factory_spec.rb ./spec/logic/style_converter_spec.rb 
./spec/models/document_spec.rb ./spec/models/keyword_list_spec.rb ./spec/models/map_spec.rb 
./spec/models/related_keyword_spec.rb
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1222:in `initialize': fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::Error)
```

However, I injected some code into the PGConnection here:

```
# Connects to a PostgreSQL server and sets up the adapter depending on the
# connected server's characteristics.
def connect
puts Rails.env
puts @connection_parameters.inspect
@connection = PGconn.connect(*@connection_parameters)
# etc.
```

The output is (I find this a little odd but might be part and parcel of the connection object?):

```
test
["", 5432, nil, nil, "projectname_test", "postgres", "mypassword"]
test
["", 5432, nil, nil, "postgres", "postgres", "mypassword"]
test
["", 5432, nil, nil, "projectname_test", "postgres", "mypassword"]
test
["", 5432, nil, nil, "postgres", "postgres", "mypassword"]
test
["", 5432, nil, nil, "projectname_test", "postgres", "mypassword"]
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "bookmarks_id_seq" for serial column "bookmarks.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "bookmarks_pkey" for table "bookmarks"

#.... a whole bunch more of these....

/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -S rspec ...many *_spec.rb files
test
["localhost", 5432, nil, nil, "projectname_test", nil, nil]
/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1224:in `initialize': fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::Error)
/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -S rspec lots_of_spec_files_spec.rb failed
```

More:

- If I just run `bundle exec rspec spec/` in the terminal it runs fine. However, if I run `bundle exec cucumber` it throws this error. I can run cucumber with any other project and it's fine.
- If I run a rake task in the terminal it runs `/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby -S rspec ...many *_spec.rb files` and this fails with the error above.

EDIT: Added some more output as suggested.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is cucumber using the `test` env or is it using it's own environment? Print `Rails.env` with that other info you're printing already to check it out.

Comment: Hi @MaurícioLinhares - Cucumber is using the `test` env.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to work around this error was to put all the db configuration to `trust` from `md5` and create a new postgres user with the same name as my login on my Ubuntu box.

Not a great solution, I'll admit, but it got it going. Since I don't use my db for anything other than dev.